# How can I save data from dynamically added inputs into database table using SQL?

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, asp.net, webforms

I need some help in explaining to me how I can save data from dynamically added inputs to my SQL database table.

What I am doing is creating an online quote / invoice web site whereby one can create the quote and then save the data or print to pdf.  (I am currently working on the "save the data" bit :-) )

So by adding the input fields (text boxes) I use a java script as per below:

```
(function (document) {
var
    head = document.head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.documentElement,
    elements = 'article aside audio bdi canvas data datalist details figcaption figure footer header 
    hgroup mark meter nav output picture progress section summary time video x'.split(' '),
    elementsLength = elements.length,
    elementsIndex = 0,
    element;

while (elementsIndex < elementsLength) {
    element = document.createElement(elements[++elementsIndex]);
}

element.innerHTML = 'x<style>' +
    'article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,nav,section{display:block}' +
    'audio[controls],canvas,video{display:inline-block}' +
    '[hidden],audio{display:none}' +
    'mark{background:#FF0;color:#000}' +
    '</style>';

return head.insertBefore(element.lastChild, head.firstChild);
})(document);

(function (window, ElementPrototype, ArrayPrototype, polyfill) {
function NodeList() { [polyfill] }
NodeList.prototype.length = ArrayPrototype.length;

ElementPrototype.matchesSelector = ElementPrototype.matchesSelector ||
    ElementPrototype.mozMatchesSelector ||
    ElementPrototype.msMatchesSelector ||
    ElementPrototype.oMatchesSelector ||
    ElementPrototype.webkitMatchesSelector ||
    function matchesSelector(selector) {
        return ArrayPrototype.indexOf.call(this.parentNode.querySelectorAll(selector), this) > -1;
    };

ElementPrototype.ancestorQuerySelectorAll = ElementPrototype.ancestorQuerySelectorAll ||
    ElementPrototype.mozAncestorQuerySelectorAll ||
    ElementPrototype.msAncestorQuerySelectorAll ||
    ElementPrototype.oAncestorQuerySelectorAll ||
    ElementPrototype.webkitAncestorQuerySelectorAll ||
    function ancestorQuerySelectorAll(selector) {
        for (var cite = this, newNodeList = new NodeList; cite = cite.parentElement;) {
            if (cite.matchesSelector(selector)) ArrayPrototype.push.call(newNodeList, cite);
        }

        return newNodeList;
    };

ElementPrototype.ancestorQuerySelector = ElementPrototype.ancestorQuerySelector ||
    ElementPrototype.mozAncestorQuerySelector ||
    ElementPrototype.msAncestorQuerySelector ||
    ElementPrototype.oAncestorQuerySelector ||
    ElementPrototype.webkitAncestorQuerySelector ||
    function ancestorQuerySelector(selector) {
        return this.ancestorQuerySelectorAll(selector)[0] || null;
    };
})(this, Element.prototype, Array.prototype);


function generateTableRow() {
var emptyColumn = document.createElement('tr');


emptyColumn.innerHTML = '<td><a class="cut" title="Remove Item">-</a><span contenteditable></span> 
</td>' +
    '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>' +
    '<td><span data-prefix>₹</span><span contenteditable>0.00</span></td>' +
    '<td><span contenteditable>1</span></td>' +
    '<td><span data-prefix>₹</span><span>0.00</span></td>';

return emptyColumn;
}

function parseFloatHTML(element) {
return parseFloat(element.innerHTML.replace(/[^\d\.\-]+/g, '')) || 0;
}

function parsePrice(number) {
return number.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1,');
}

function updateNumber(e) {
var
    activeElement = document.activeElement,
    value = parseFloat(activeElement.innerHTML),
    wasPrice = activeElement.innerHTML == parsePrice(parseFloatHTML(activeElement));

if (!isNaN(value) && (e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 40 || e.wheelDeltaY)) {
    e.preventDefault();

    value += e.keyCode == 38 ? 1 : e.keyCode == 40 ? -1 : Math.round(e.wheelDelta * 0.025);
    value = Math.max(value, 0);

    activeElement.innerHTML = wasPrice ? parsePrice(value) : value;
}

updateInvoice();
}


function updateInvoice() {
var total = 0;
var cells, price, total, a, i;


for (var a = document.querySelectorAll('table.inventory tbody tr'), i = 0; a[i]; ++i) {
    // get inventory row cells
    cells = a[i].querySelectorAll('span:last-child');

    // set price as cell[2] * cell[3]
    price = parseFloatHTML(cells[2]) * parseFloatHTML(cells[3]);

    // add price to total
    total += price;

    // set row total
    cells[4].innerHTML = price;
}

// get label cells
label_cells = document.querySelectorAll('table.balance th span:last-child');
tax_rate = label_cells[1].innerHTML / 100;

// get balance cells
cells = document.querySelectorAll('table.balance td:last-child span:last-child');

// set total
cells[0].innerHTML = total;

// set tax
cells[1].innerHTML = parsePrice(total * tax_rate);

// set balance and meta balance
cells[2].innerHTML = document.querySelector('table.meta tr:last-child td:last-child span:last- 
child').innerHTML = parsePrice(total + parseFloatHTML(cells[1]));

var prefix = document.querySelector('#prefix').innerHTML;
for (a = document.querySelectorAll('[data-prefix]'), i = 0; a[i]; ++i) a[i].innerHTML = prefix;

for (a = document.querySelectorAll('span[data-prefix] + span'), i = 0; a[i]; ++i) if 
(document.activeElement != a[i]) a[i].innerHTML = parsePrice(parseFloatHTML(a[i]));
}

function onContentLoad() {
updateInvoice();

var
    input = document.querySelector('input'),
    image = document.querySelector('img');

function onClick(e) {
    var element = e.target.querySelector('[contenteditable]'), row;

    element && e.target != document.documentElement && e.target != document.body && element.focus();

    if (e.target.matchesSelector('.add')) {
        document.querySelector('table.inventory tbody').appendChild(generateTableRow());
    }
    else if (e.target.className == 'cut') {
        row = e.target.ancestorQuerySelector('tr');

        row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
    }

    updateInvoice();
}

function onEnterCancel(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    image.classList.add('hover');
}

function onLeaveCancel(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    image.classList.remove('hover');
}

function onFileInput(e) {
    image.classList.remove('hover');

    var
        reader = new FileReader(),
        files = e.dataTransfer ? e.dataTransfer.files : e.target.files,
        i = 0;

    reader.onload = onFileLoad;

    while (files[i]) reader.readAsDataURL(files[i++]);
}

function onFileLoad(e) {
    var data = e.target.result;

    image.src = data;
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('click', onClick);

    document.addEventListener('mousewheel', updateNumber);
    document.addEventListener('keydown', updateNumber);

    document.addEventListener('keydown', updateInvoice);
    document.addEventListener('keyup', updateInvoice);

    input.addEventListener('focus', onEnterCancel);
    input.addEventListener('mouseover', onEnterCancel);
    input.addEventListener('dragover', onEnterCancel);
    input.addEventListener('dragenter', onEnterCancel);

    input.addEventListener('blur', onLeaveCancel);
    input.addEventListener('dragleave', onLeaveCancel);
    input.addEventListener('mouseout', onLeaveCancel);

    input.addEventListener('drop', onFileInput);
    input.addEventListener('change', onFileInput);
}
}

window.addEventListener && document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onContentLoad);


function serial_file() {
document.getElementById("serial").value = Date.now();
}

function un_serial_file() {
document.getElementById("serial").value = "";
}

var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if (dd < 10) {
dd = '0' + dd;
}

if (mm < 10) {
mm = '0' + mm;
}



today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
today_form = yyyy + '-' + dd + '-' + mm + ' ';
var serial = Date.now();

function myprint() {
window.print();
}
```

And on my "NewQuote.aspx" Page I have this:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div style="display: inline-block; float: left;">
                                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="drpClientSelect" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList><br />
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="First Name" ID="lblFirstName"></asp:Label><br />
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Last Name" ID="lblLastName"></asp:Label><br />
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Company Name" ID="lblCompanyName"></asp:Label><br />
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Address" ID="lblAddress"></asp:Label><br />
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Email" ID="lblEmail"></asp:Label><br />
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Contact Number" ID="lblContactNumber"></asp:Label><br />
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Web Site Address" ID="lblWebsite"></asp:Label><br />
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <div>
                                <table class="meta" id="top_data_table">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr class="" id="invoice_number_row">
                                            <th class="bold"><span class="invoice" id="invoice">Invoice&nbsp;#</span></th>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" name="fname" /></td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr id="daterow">
                                            <th class="bold"><span class="date" id="date">Date</span></th>
                                            <td><span>
                                                <input type="date" id="theDate" /></span></td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr class="" id="total_block">
                                            <th class="bold"><span class="amount" id="amount">Ammout</span></th>
                                            <td><span id="prefix">R</span><span></span></td>
                                        </tr>

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                        <br />
                        <div class="min_height">
                            <table class="inventory">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="bold">
                                            <span class="item" id="item">Item</span>
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="bold">
                                            <span class="description" id="description">Description</span>
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="bold">
                                            <span class="rate" id="rate">Rate</span>
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="bold">
                                            <span class="quantity" id="quantity">Quantity</span>
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="bold">
                                            <span class="price" id="price">Price</span>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <a class="cut" title="Remove Item">-</a>
                                            <span contenteditable="true"></span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <span contenteditable="true"></span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <span data-prefix="">R</span>
                                            <span contenteditable="true">0.00</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <span contenteditable="true">1</span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <span data-prefix="">R</span><span>0.00</span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <a class="add noprint" title="Add Item">+</a>
                            <div class="left_btn">
                                <button class="mah_btn" onclick="myprint()">Print</button>
                                <button class="mah_btn" onclick="window.location.reload()">Reset</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="right_tax">
                                <table class="balance" id="balance">
                                    <tbody>

                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="bold">
                                                <span class="subtotal" id="subtotal">Subtotal</span>
                                            </th>
                                            <td>
                                                <span>R</span><span>0.00</span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="bold">
                                                <span class="tax" id="tax" contenteditable="true">Include VAT&nbsp;</span>
                                                <span contenteditable="true">0</span>%
                                            </th>
                                            <td>
                                                <span>R</span><span>0.00</span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="bold">
                                                <span class="total" id="total">Total</span>
                                            </th>
                                            <td>
                                                <span>R</span><span>0.00</span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

So the end results looks like this (with the CSS ofcourse :-) )

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRy06.png)

As you can see you can add a new row and insert some data.  If you hover over the input line a "minues" sign will popup where you can delete that row.  It will also automatically multiply and add the necassary fields to display total amount.  All of this works great, but I now want to save it to my SQL database table.  For this I have created the table and looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_newQuotes] (
[Id]          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Item] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Description]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Rate]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Quantity]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Price] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

And as you can guess this is where I am stuck :-(   No I have saved form data before which is realtively simple by supllying the TextBox ID and values and save that to the database.  But this is a complete different ball game and am not sure on how to achieve that.

I have covered most things in the question, but if you require more info please let me know.

**EDIT**

If there is a simpler way maybe to achieve this I am all ears :-)  Maybe a tutorial on creating an invoice / quotation web forms app?

I have tried now again and can't seem to figure it out :-(

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I want you to approach it in a different way by using a GridView control.
When you click the "+" button, you save a row you have added into the table; bind the gridview taking records from the table; and display the rows including the necessary fields calculated like total amount.

There is another way by using a DataTable. Create a DataTable and save those rows to the DataTable. Then put another button called "Save" which makes those records in the DataTable saved into the Table. After saving and refreshing the screen, bring the records saved to the DataTable to display the rows on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you are using jquery, it is possible to do by creating the JSON object of the inputs you added.

1. Create JSON object for multiple rows
2. Make an ajax call to pass the JSON object to web method.
3. Populate datatable with parsing the JSON object
4. Create user defined table Type in SQL for the datatable we wish to pass.
5. Pass datatable to Stored procedure and in SP process the data as you want.